# Best practice for working on an android library

Tags: android, kotlin

We have some Android Applications which share data models and other stuff. So my plan was to make a library for that which can be easily extended and implemented in these Apps and maybe also in future Apps.

What is the best approach for that?

For just testing around, I implemented a module to one of the Apps. But this has the problem that it is bound to this single project and its version control which makes it a pain in the b_ to maintain. Also its not practicable to work on because everyone has to have and work on this App project for library changes.

My thoughts were to separate them but how? I have researched alot and didnt find a way to create a standalone library. The only way Ive found so far was to create a whole new Android Project and manage the library in it and seperate it from the :app Module. I dont know but this doesnt feels straight forward.
What is a good way to manage a library which has its own version control and can be easily maintained from everyone? Is the own Android Project the way to go?

Comment: I won't downvote your question but know that this question is not suitable for StackOverflow and you should read the guidelines on How to post a question on StackOverflow

Answer (score 1):

You can still setup a separated VCS for a module and maintain it in another repository. [git-submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) is a way around it.

As you've mentioned, another approach is to create a new Android project for the library and distribute it separately. It's very straitforward way, but it's simple less error prone.